# Convert outside image links to imgur links on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, images, uploader

The only viable option to include an internet-hosted image on the iOS app without having to type the Markdown manually is by saving it locally then re-uploading it. Both the web version, mobile version and Android version have this feature to mitigate the workload, I expect to have this feature on the iOS app too.

The upload from URL button is what I need, and the upload from camera is what I've never used.

[image: iOS app with only options to upload or to use camera]

For comparison, here's the buttons in the Android app:

[image: Android app with options to upload or use URL]