# How do I add an inline photo from a URL on the iOS mobile app?

Tags: support, edits, ios-app, images

The question is pretty self explanatory. I want to add an image to a post from a URL like I can on the web version of Stack Exchange.

Specifically, if I’m browsing from the iOS mobile app and I see someone with low rep who uploaded a photo and provided a link, I can’t edit the post and use the link to inline the image on the post. Instead I can only add my own photo from my photo library.

Comment: Related [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299313/339911).

Comment: Well, the android app [has a shortcut](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246405/allow-us-to-link-to-an-image-online).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just edit the Markdown and modify the linked image

```
[enter link description here](https://example.com/image.jpg)
```

by adding a `!` in front of it:

```
![enter link description here](https://example.com/image.jpg)
```

This works in the mobile app just as well as in a desktop browser.

---

Doing that converts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCtCd.png)

into

[image]

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I figured it was something simple like that. I’ll give it a try next time, but I’m sure it will work. Would be nice if it was more obvious in the mobile app though. Thanks!